# Should the variable of interest always be placed in the numerator when creating predictive ratios?

Tags: regression, cox-model, normalization, aic, ratio

Background:

I do research in medical imaging. In a current study I am analyzing a measured variable from images that may predict prognosis/survival. Studies of potential imaging survival predictors are common.

It is often beneficial to perform some kind of normalization to negate scanner/examination/patient-related effects that might introduce increased variability in the measurement of interest and mask the potential biological signal that you are interested in measuring. The method often found useful is some kind of ratio, for example, tumor/measurement in normal tissue. An example of a study(There are many examples): https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/29383647/

I have 2 questions:

1. In virtually all the studies I have explored the variable of interest (tumor measurement) is put in the numerator, while the reference variable (normal tissue measurement) is put in the denominator. This seems plausible from an intuitive point of reference, since you ratio the variable of interest with the reference variable. However, it is not clear to me why you can not do the reverse with the reference variable in the numerator: (normal tissue measurement)/(tumor variable). I would think that it would depend on actual measured values: It would be a bad idea to put a variable with values approaching zero in the denominator.

In my data the (normal tissue measurement)/(tumor variable)-ratio yields a better AIC in the Cox-regression than the (tumor variable)/(normal tissue measurement) (430 vs.434) (442 for the non-normalized tumor variable. The histograms of the ratios and and non-normalized variable of interest can be seen below.

[image: histogram of the (normal tissue measurement)/(tumor variable)-ratio]

[image: histogram of the (tumor variable)/(normal tissue measurement)-ratio]

[image: histogram of the non-normalized tumor variable]

The question is: Is there any reason not to use the (normal tissue measurement)/(tumor variable)-ratio? And why is the inverse (tumor variable)/(normal tissue measurement) always the standard in these situations?

Question 2:

This question is about how the survival predictive capabilities of these variables relate to the coefficient of variation (CV). The CV is higher for the (normal tissue measurement)/(tumor variable)-ratio than for the (tumor variable)/(normal tissue measurement) (0.23 vs.0.21) and even lower for the non-normalized tumor variable (0.19).

So there seems to be an inverse relation between the goodness of fit for survival prediction and the coefficient of variability.

I have also identified variables related to the imaging examination parameters that have a significant relation to the value of the measured tumor variable in linear regression. These relations are negated by adding the (normal tissue measurement) to the linear regression model. My interpretation is that normalizing to a reference tissue negates the variance of the technical variables while retaining the biological information I am interested in and may have prognostic predictive value. However, I am somewhat puzzled by the seemingly increase in variability after normalization, as I would expect lower values of the coefficient of variability post-normalization. If anyone can shed some light on this it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the range of values found for both numbers is bounded well away from zero, then it won't make much difference which way you take the ratio - the two options will have an approximately linear relationship anyway.

If normal tissues have large values, and disease tissues sometimes have small values, then the conventional approach will work well, except in one case: if the distinction you care about is the difference between "small" and "very small" then using the inverse might be helpful.

If disease tissues have large values, and normal tissues can have small or even zero values, then the conventional approach will run into trouble, and your idea of using the inverse will work well.

Here is a another option: try the log of the ratio. Then it doesn't matter which you use as the numerator - it just changes the sign of the log.

A lot of statistical methods make an assumption of linearity. This is only sometimes appropriate. It is good to look at the data and consider possible transformations before using a linear method - as you are doing.

Comment: (+1) for emphasizing the importance of checking the linearity assumption in the regression. I suspect that's why the OP finds a difference between `rat1` and `rat2`.